# Core Data: Errors vs Exceptions Part 2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, debugging, core-data, nsexception

My question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1224878/core-data-hoping-for-errors-getting-exceptions), but I need further clarification. I often get exceptions during code like this:

```
NSError* error;
if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to save to data store: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

However, when I put a breakpoint in `objc_exception_throw`, I can find out that an exception is thrown in `save`:

```
(gdb) po [$eax name]
NSInternalInconsistencyException
(gdb) po [$eax description]
optimistic locking failure
```

I wouldn't expect this, since the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdTroubleshooting.html) say that an optimistic locking failure will return an error, not an exception.

As an aside, I can't even seem to catch this exception with `@try ...  @catch (NSException * e)` in the code. It's all strange.

Answer (score 2):

I think what's happening is that `objc_exception_throw` is catching internal exceptions in Core Data, but they really aren't percolating to my app. Because I set my merge policy, the locking failures are getting converted into object merges and all is well.

I should probably also use `committedValuesForKeys:` so I can see what's going on before the exceptions .. this doesn't happen every time.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your own answers if they solve the issue.

Comment: Looking into a similar issue myself. It does seem that the exception is thrown internally but is resolved by the merge policy: if I use a general exception breakpoint I catch the exception on the background context's thread. However, if I set another breakpoint after the save operation I can see that the save return `YES` and the error is `nil`... As such it would *seem* to be a non-issue. I hope so anyway!